# Depth of a relationship

Tags: c#, lambda, .net-4.5

I'm trying to figure out how to get the depth of a relationship of an entity that can relate to itself. That is There is a base comment item, which can have one or more reply comments linked to it.

Now for each one of these replied comments I want to know how deep they are from the top node.

ie, I want to know the Depth in the comments in the image below:

[image: Comment levels]

This is the code as of now, and the variable `ResponseTo` is the relationship that this comment is a response to, if is is not a response the value is `null`

```
var comments = db.Comments
.Where(c => c.Post.ID == id && c.Status == Helpers.StatusCode.Visible)
.Select(x => new CommentTemp()
    {
        Id = x.ID,
        Text = x.Text,
        Avatar = "-1",
        Username = (x.User != null ? x.User.UserName : "Anonymous"),
        UserID = (x.User != null ? (int?) x.User.Id : null),
        ResponseTo = (x.ResponseTo == null ?  null : (int?) x.ResponseTo.ID),
        CommentDepth = ??? // <--- how do i select the depth of the response to relations?
        Created = x.Created
    })
.ToList();
```

Only option I can think of right now is saving it as the comment is created, but if possible I would like to get it on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it indeed sounds like you want to hold such information in the database, unless there's **really** good reason not to. Either way, Linq is not really recursive friendly.

You can get the depth by creating dictionary & tracking it back recursively.

```
int GetDepth(Comment comment, 
                IDictionary<int, Comment> comments,  /*key=commentId, val=Comment*/
                IDictionary<int, int> depthMemoization, /* key=commentId, val=depth*/
                int currentDepth = 0)
{
    if(depthMemoization.ContainsKey(comment.Id))
        return depthMemoization[comment.Id];

    if(comment.ParentId==null)
        return currentDepth;

    var parentComment = comments[comment.ParentId.Value];

    int calculatedDepth = GetDepth(parentComment, comments, 
                            depthMemoization,
                            ++currentDepth);

    depthMemoization[comment.Id] = calculatedDepth ;

    return depth;
}
```